# How can you test an email link with Protractor?

Tags: javascript, testing, protractor, angularjs-e2e, end-to-end

I'm writing tests with Protractor and I want to find out how can I test an email link. I mean, it's easy to test a normal link because you have just to check out the new URL. But when you click on an email link, you can go to an external email provider so, is there any solution?
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You **should not be testing this kind of functionality** - it lies far beyond the functionality of your application. What would happen after the click on that link would differ from system-to-system, browser-to-browser and it is not something under `protractor`'s or `selenium`'s control.

The only thing you should check is that there is `mailto:` in the `href` of the link.